# Binary symmetric channel, Average probability of error goes to zero

Tags: information-theory

Let us have the following definition: We have a *W* which is an alphabet with |W| = $2^n$ (the number of elements), and a codebook *C* which maps uniquely each element of the alphabet to the binary sequence of length *n*. 
The code is sent over the n-th extension of the binary symmetric channel with crossover probability of *p* , that is, P[X=1, Y=0] = P[X=0, Y=1] = p. When received, it is decoded with $C^{-1}$.

My question is, how can we find and show conditions on *p* so that the average probability of error of the channel goes to zero, as $n \rightarrow \infty $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacity of the binary symmetric channel is $1-H(p)$ where $H(p)$ is the Shannon entropy of a Bernoulli(p) distribution (see, for example, Cover and Thomas, Elements of Information Theory 2e, Chapter 7).

The rate of a (M,n) code (which maps M input values to a binary vector of length $n$) is $\frac{\log M }{n}$.

The channel coding theorem says that you can achieve any rate below the capacity (i.e. the average/maximum probability of error goes to zero).

In your case, it looks like you want a $(2^n,n)$ code, which has rate $1$, so you can only communicate with vanishing probability of error if $p=0,1$.

Comment: How do you actually get $p = 0,1$?

Comment: Entropy is 0 for those two values. If p=0, you get the input at the output. If p=1, you get the inverted input at the output. In either case, you can perfectly map the output to the input.

Comment: Okay, so for p=0 or p=1 $H(p) = 0$. Then the capacity will be exactly 1...how does that relate to the rate of the code? Any why do we want a rate of 1? However, can you show that the average error probability goes to 0 when $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: You should read my answer (or chapter 7 of Cover & Thomas, Elements of Information Theory 2e). The channel coding theorem tells you rates which are achievable (and otherwise, average/maximal probability of error goes to 1).